# Swift: How do I programmatically add and resize textView to cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, textview

I'm trying to add a textView to a cell programmatically because I can't use the storyboard for this situation. The below code is my incomplete understanding of how to accomplish this.  What I don't know is how to size it to not only match the size (width and height) of the cell, but to resize both the cell and textView to match the amount of text entered.

```
var textView: UITextView = UITextView(//what goes here??)

cell.addSubview(textView)
```

I found a similar question for objective C, but not only do I not know objective C, it didn't quite cover the question.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that you need to declare a custom class for this?

Comment: No I was not aware. Let me know if you can help me accomplish this.

Comment: Yeah I'm going to write an answer for you, just wait 15 to 20 minutes ;)

Comment: Are you using storyboard for this or do you make all this programmatically?

Comment: I'm doing it all programmatically without a storyboard.

Comment: Well, ok then I'll edit my answer for you

Comment: Yeah it's because I have two sections and they both have a single cell doing different things, one of which is the one I need the textView inside of. Thanks a ton, I can already see where it's going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing with it for hours and learning a bunch of stuff from Oliver, I finally figured it out. Turns out it's quite simple to get the textView into the cell, but making both the cell and the textView dynamically grow as you type is apparently another feat entirely.  This mostly accomplishes the goal, but I am not satisfied with manually setting the height to 100.

```
    var cellIdentifier = ""

    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        cellIdentifier = "CellSection1"
        tableView.rowHeight = 100
        cell.frame.size.height = 100
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        var textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.size.width, height: cell.frame.size.height))
        cell.addSubview(textView)
        return cell

    } else {

        cellIdentifier = "CellSection0"
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)
        cell.textLabel?.text = entry.thoughtText
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

So you have to do the following, I think it it well commented. Remember: You have to set at least 1 dynamic prototype cell for your table view in the storyboard and then customize the way you want to do that. Then connect all your outlets with outlet properties in your custom UITableViewCell class -> see the following:

```
// you don't need to do anything else here when creating your table view cell in your storyboard
// as all the required functions can be used from the superclass UITableViewCell
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var myTextView: UITextView!
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    //already initialized from the storyboard
    @IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //need to set table view's delegate and data source
    myTableView.delegate = self
    myTableView.dataSource = self
}

// MARK: TableView source
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5 //usually you have an array and you return array.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //watch out, your identifier has to be the same as in the storyboard. 
    // When selecting your cell in the storyboard you can set this identifier in the attributes inspector
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyTableViewCell
    cell.myTextView.text = "myName" //usually you do: array[indexPath.row] -> example for an array of strings
    return cell
}

//when setting and text view, you probably want a quite big table view cell so you have to do the following
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 60 //the height of your table view cell, the default value is 44
}
}
```

Hope this works, tell me if you have any problems

Update: programmatically

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
var myTextView: UITextView!
override init() {
    super.init()
    myTextView = UITextView(frame: self.frame)
    self.addSubview(myTextView)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}

class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var myTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    //need to set table view's delegate and data source
     //maybe style grouped looks better for more section table view
    myTableView = UITableView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame, style: .Grouped)
    myTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    myTableView.delegate = self
    myTableView.dataSource = self
}

// MARK: TableView source
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel!.text = "myText"
        return cell
    } else { //custom cell for section 2
        let cell = MyTableViewCell()
        cell.myTextView.text = "myName"
        return cell
    }
}

//when setting and text view, you probably want a quite big table view cell so you have to do the following
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        return 44
    }
    return 60 //the height of your table view cell, the default value is 44
}
}
```

By the way for adjusting your text view's size to the text inside simply do: `cell.myTextView.sizeToFit()`.

Comment: For some reason it can't see myTextView. UITableViewCell does not have member "myTextView", when I do cell.myTextView.text = "anything".  Trying to figure out what's missing. Also if I didn't set the text for myTextView.text I get another error that says fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(frame:)' for class 'appname.MyTableViewCell'

Comment: Oh wait I'm sorry I forgot a line of code in the viewDidLoad() function

Comment: `myTableView.registerClass(MyTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "someIdentifier")`.

Comment: I'm not totally sure if this works due to your two different classes, so you could also try to use `UITableViewCell.self` instead of `MyTableViewCell.self`

Comment: I'm realizing if just the TableViewController is set up in the storyboard but the prototype cells are not, and that's pointing to a TableViewController I have set up, then of course I don't need some of the code above (though that's incredibly educational). However, I'll have to refactor how that MyTableViewCell class is registered in that case. I'm not quite sure how to go about that. I've tried putting the tableView.registerClass(MyTableViewCell... above into the viewDidLoad(), also tried putting it down in the cellForRowAtIndexPath. No such luck.

Comment: I updated my main post with the full cellForRowAtIndexPath, it works great if I just make it like the other cell but then there's no textView of course.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67738/discussion-between-oliver-borchert-and-sephethus).